# problems with subdivision surface

Tags: subdivision-surface

right now im modelling some glasses, and im having a problem with the "subdivision surface" modifier, basically it connects points i don't want to connect...

without subdivision surface:
[image: without subdivision surface:]

and with subdivision surface:
[image]

[here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/y14juacznygzzzp/glasses_1_3.blend/file) the blenderfile download (mediafire)

i would really appreciate some help :)

edit:
Thanks to Paul,

i got it working by removing the exchange the big face with smaller ones:

[image: Woking]

Comment: your topology is bad, why all these ngons, try to extrude with quads only, then you'll create some additional edge loops to sharp the angles you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this huge n-gon (a face with more than 4 vertices) which is a problem when using subdivision surface (and more generally, it's a problem for pretty much everything else too).

[image]

From looking at the model I think you had a picture of the profile of the glasses, you then extruded a plane following the profile, then extruded the plane inward to get the thickness and then you just pressed F to fill the remaning hole. That's not going to work. You need quads everywhere. You can either fill each quad manually or try to bridge the loops, but this model is a bit messy.

Comment: N-gons are not always bad.

Comment: ok thank you for the help, i will try it later and tell you if it worked :D

Comment: it worked, thank you...